jvm-test-suite throws unexpected groovy warning in intellij
I am trying to use jvm-test-suite in a sample gradle app, however I am getting

'suites' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

This is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jvm-test-suite'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }

        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                implementation project()
            }

            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn(testing.suites.integrationTest)
}

I am using JDK17, and gradle 8.6. I see the issue in intellij 2023.1, 2023.3, and 2024.1

Seems to be a known issue (IDEA-324748)
